# Changin beheaviour of django-two-factor-auth package

Tags: django

I have being using django-two-factor-auth package and it was really simple to set up. Unfortunately my boss wants to do some changes which more advanced for my junior level.

Firstly, we are working in a type of browser dashboard web app and so all users needs to authenticate before logging in. So the first view needs to be the login.

Secondly, i was asked that if the user hasnt enabled the two-factor qr code, the authentication needs to redirect the user to the set up view to enable it. So users wont be able to use the app unless they have the 2FA enabled.

How can i achieve this? I tried to dig into the documentation but im feelling too lost right now and i would appreciate some insight on the matter.

Thank you all.

I tried looking into the documentation but got lost on it. Then i tried to see if i can change the package code but couldnt find it.
Also tried to add a path with name 'login' but it doesnt work.

Comment: Use `login required decorater` and redirect to login view and create a `auth2factorrequired` decorator and use both on every view except login, register and factoryauth views. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator